# should it be a Type A record resource for mail server?

Tags: dns

I was reading a textbook which says:

> When you register the domain name networkutopia.com with some
> registrar, you also need to provide the registrar with the names and
> IP addresses of your primary and secondary authoritative DNS servers.
> Suppose the names and IP addresses are `dns1.networkutopia.com`,
> `dns2.networkutopia.com`, `212.2.212.1`, and `212.212.212.2`. For each
> of these two authoritative DNS servers, the registrar would then make
> sure that a Type NS and a Type A record are entered into the TLD com
> servers. Specifically, for the primary authoritative server for
> `networkutopia.com`, the registrar would insert the following two
> resource records into the DNS system:
>
> ```
> (networkutopia.com, dns1.networkutopia.com, NS) 
> (dns1.networkutopia.com, 212.212.212.1, A)
> ```
>
> You’ll also have to make sure that the Type A resource record for
> your Web server `www.networkutopia.com` and the Type MX resource
> record for your mail server `mail.networkutopia.com` are entered into
> your authoritative DNS servers.

My questions are:

Q1-Is the Type A resource record for web server sth like:

```
(www.networkutopia.com, xxx.xx.xx.xxx, A)
```

Q2-should it also be a Type A resource record for the mail server in the authoritative DNS server as:

```
(mail.networkutopia.com, xxx.xx.xx.xxx, A)
```

otherwise, without the Type A resource record for mail server,  how can the sender know the ip address of the mail server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the Type A resource record for a web server something like `(www.networkutopia.com, xxx.xx.xx.xxx, A)`?

The exact format probably varies by DNS server, but for [BIND](https://www.isc.org/bind/) it would likely be similar:

```
networkutopia.com.    IN A    xxx.xx.xx.xxx
```

The record above assumes someone would want the web server to be available via `networkutopia.com` (i.e. without `www`). That is, while there is nothing preventing someone from using ex.:

```
www.networkutopia.com.    IN A    xxx.xx.xx.xxx
```

as their primary A record for a web server, technically `www` is a subdomain of `networkutopia.com`.

> Should there also be a Type A resource record for the mail server in the authoritative DNS server as `(mail.networkutopia.com, xxx.xx.xx.xxx, A)`?

There could be an A record for ex. `mail.networkutopia.com`:

```
mail.networkutopia.com.    IN A    xxx.xx.xx.xxx
```

However, there would also need to be an MX record as well:

```
networkutopia.com.    IN MX 10    mail.networkutopia.com.
```

Note that A records aren't always required. "Out-of-zone" mail servers can be used as well (without an accompanying A record) e.g.:

```
networkutopia.com.    IN MX 10    mail.example.com.
```

In the example above, `mail.example.com` would receive the email traffic for `networkutopia.com`.